# Returning and accessing JSON fields in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a model called EmploymentApplication that uses a JSON field to hold all of the submitted form data when someone submits their application.  This field is simply called "data".  I'm working on the resource controller's 'index' method.  I only want to return the id, and the first name and last name (that's inside the 'data' JSON field).

I'm trying to figure it out in Tinker (there is currently only one application in the DB):

`$result = \App\Models\EmploymentApplications\EmploymentApplication::all(['id', 'data->fname', 'data->lname'])`

returns:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#888
 all: [
   App\Models\EmploymentApplications\EmploymentApplication {#881
     id: 1,
     `data`->'$."fname"': ""Betty"",
     `data`->'$."lname"': ""Sue"",
   },
 ],
```

}

So, It's returning the correct data.  The part that has me stumped is how to access that data->fname and data->lname from here.

`$result[0]->id` works just fine.

`$result[0]->(backtick)data(backtick)->'$."lname"'`

throws:

PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected '`', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' on line 1

What is the correct way to access these properties?

I know I could just use array_map to clean up the result before returning it from the controller, but what is the best practice here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use column aliases:

```php
$result = EmploymentApplication::all(['id', 'data->fname as fname', 'data->lname as lname']);
$result[0]->fname
$result[0]->lname
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, but if I am using **tinker** and want to get information from my database, this is what I use.

```
DB::select("SELECT id, fname, lname FROM EmploymentApplication")
```

or if you are looking for a specific id.

```
DB::select("SELECT id, fname, lname FROM EmploymentApplication WHERE id=1")
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the properties data->fname and data->lname from the result, you need to use the -> operator with the string keys directly. However, since the keys contain special characters (such as ->), you'll need to use curly braces {} to access them. Here's how you can do it:

```
$result[0]->{'data->fname'}
$result[0]->{'data->lname'}
```

So, in your case, to access the first name and last name:

`$firstName = $result[0]->{'data->fname'}; $lastName = $result[0]->{'data->lname'};`

This should allow you to access the properties correctly.